# Which kind for filter to protect eyes from LED's blue light : UV(A), UV(B) or UV(C)?

Tags: uv-rays, led-lights, visible-optical-spectrum

I heard about the so called "retinal light toxicity" that the blue light from LED lighting may cause.

I would like to mount a filter on the objective of my microscope to reduce the risk of injuries, but there are different kind of filters depending on the spectrum.
I could not find any trivial information telling if one should filter the blue in the visible spectrum, UVA, UVB or UVC?

So, for which kind of UV should the filter be, and if for all three, does this imply a multi-coated filter?